# Template filled by an operator

Tags: c++, templates, operators

Can you use templates (or the like) in C++ to specify which operation is done in a function?

I don't know how to explain it more clearly, so I'll show you how it could be (but isn't) done in code:

```
template <operator OPERATION> int getMaxOrMin(int a, int b) {
    return a OPERATION b ? a : b;
}
```

where finding the maximum or the minimum of a or b would be (this is where my pseudo-syntax gets a little confusing, bear with me):

```
int max = getMaxOrMin< > > (a, b);
int min = getMaxOrMin< < > (a, b);
```

I know that's not how to do it at all (because it doesn't even syntactically make sense), but I hope that clarifies the type of thing I want to do.

The reason behind me wondering this is I'm making a PriorityQueue implementation, and it would be nice to easily switch between the backing being a max-heap or a min-heap on the fly without copying and pasting code to make two different classes.

I know I could do it with a macro, but the only way I'd know how to do that would give me either a max-heap or a min-heap, but not both in the same compilation. I'm probably overlooking a way, though.

Comment: You could make one base class and have max-heap / min-heap as child classes and then make the getMaxorMin function virtual in the base class and implement it differently in max-heap/min-heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but you need to define it like a functor:

```
template <typename OPERATION>
int getMaxOrMin(int a, int b)
{
    OPERATION  operation;
    return operation(a, b) ? a : b;
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
struct myLess
{
    bool operator()(int a,int b) const { return a < b; }
}
struct myGreat
{
    bool operator()(int a,int b) const { return a > b; }
}

void code()
{
    int x = getMaxOrMin<myLess>(5,6);
    int y = getMaxOrMin<myGreat>(5,6);
}
```

That seems like a lot of work. But there are a lot of predefined functors in the standard. On [this page](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html) scroll down to "6: Function Objects".
For your situation there is:

```
std::less
std::greater
```

So the code becomes:

```
template <typename OPERATION>
int getMaxOrMin(int a, int b)
{
    OPERATION  operation;
    return operation(a, b) ? a : b;
}

void codeTry2()
{
    int x = getMaxOrMin<std::less<int> >(5,6);
    int y = getMaxOrMin<std::greater<int> >(5,6);
}
```

Comment: The last code snippet is incorrect, `std::less` and `std::greater` are templates, and what you want to use is a concrete instantiation of that template: `getMaxOrMin< std::less<int> >( 5, 6 )`. Also, when using function templates (rather than class templates) the functor is commonly passed (by value) as a third argument, instead of as a type argument that needs to be constructed internally: `template <typename BinaryPredicate> int getMaxOrMin( int a, int b, Functor f );` and used as `getMaxOrMin( a, b, std::less<int>() );` I don't have a reason for this, other than consistency with STL.

Comment: Fixed std:less etc. In this context I think passing the functor as a third parameter does not add anything (actually degrades readability). But that is all context sensitive and the reader should use what is appropriate for the situation.

Answer (score 8):

Do what `std::map` and friends do: Take a comparison function/functor as your template parameter. See `std::less` and `std::greater`.

Do remember that the standard library *already* has a well developed and debugged priority queue that you can use with an arbitrary comparison function.